# Self Hosted signalR in windows service; Minimum permissions for base url = http://*:1111

Tags: windows-services, signalr, owin

I have built a windows service which runs a self hosted SignalR service.

I start the webApp thus: WebApp.Start("http://*:1111")

to get this to start I have to provide my service with an Admin logOn.  But that seems a bit too much of a privilege.

I Tried using NETWORK SERVICE  but that got access denied error.

What is the minimum privilege required to start my WebApp for the URL provided.  Or Must I run my service with Admin privileges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use netsh.exe (found in c:\Windows\System32) to allow a specified non-admin user to listen for http requests on port 1111.

The syntax for the command is as follows:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:1111/ user=DOMAIN\user
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: is that the same thing as using the HttpCfg.exe tool or easir to use HttpNamespaceManager  found on this website? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwh/archive/2007/05/04/addressaccessdeniedexception-http-could-not-register-url-http-8080.aspx

Comment: [HttpCfg.exe's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364478(v=vs.85).aspx) indicates that it is "obsolete and replaced by similar functionality in netsh.exe". So I guess it is the same thing, though I tend to shy away from using tools labeled as obsolete. As for HttpNamespaceManager, the blog you linked to states that it is "not an official Microsoft tool." However, I imagine any of these three tools would do the job.

Comment: for me the netsh needs admin rights to run. So this allows the app to listen to that url after the initial reservation. But, it's not a complete non-admin solution.